# getQuery(true) vs stdClass Class data row insertion - Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

Method 1

```
  global $database;
  $user = new stdClass;
  $user->id = NULL;
  $user->name = $name;
  $user->username = $username;

  if (!$database->insertObject( '#__users', $user, 'id' )) {
    echo $database->stderr();
    return false;
  }

  return $user->id;
```

Method 2

```
  $db = JFactory::getDBO();     
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query->insert($db->nameQuote('#__users'));
  $query->set($db->nameQuote('name').'='.$db->quote($$name).','.
  $db->nameQuote('username').'='.$db->quote($username));     
  $db->setQuery( $query );
  $db->query();
  $new_id = $db->insertId();
```

I'm using Joomla and use both above queries which lets me the get the work done. My problem is what is the difference between method 1 and method 2? What's the industry standard? Are there any specific situation I should use above methods? Which one is better and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1** (M1) and **Method 2** (M2) are both valid Joomla! 2.5 mechanisms, M1 uses a semi automated method and is probably more commonly used where you are already working with objects.

M2 is obviously a more specific set of steps but both will work the abstraction provided by `JDatabase` et. al. to isolate you from the database server.

Having said that M1 is only used in a few places (literally) in the entire Joomla! 2.5 installation (not counting `/libararies/joomla/database/`) while M2 is used extensively

The only odd thing is the use of a `global` in M1, normally [Joomla! coding standards](http://developer.joomla.org/coding-standards.html) eschew the use of globals preferring rather to use OOP or factory patterns instead. So, something like this:

```
$database = JFactory::getDBO();
```

instead of using the `global` reference.